# I have a form where I can submit text files, and i want it to add those text files to another existing form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have an html form that is used to upload text files:

```
      <div class="form">
        <h3>Upload File:</h3>
        <form action="networkSelector.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="FileUploadForm" id="FileUploadForm">
          <label for="UploadFileField"></label>
          <input type="file" name="UploadFileField" id="UploadFileField" />
          <input type="submit" name="UploadButton" id="UploadButton" value="Upload" />
        </form>
      </div>
```

The php portion of the code for the form:

```
   <?php
require('db.php');
include("auth.php");

if(isset($_FILES['UploadFileField'])){
    // Creates the Variables needed to upload the file
    $UploadName = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['name'];
    $UploadName = mt_rand(100000, 999999).$UploadName;
    $UploadTmp = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'];
    $UploadType = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['type'];
    $FileSize = $_FILES['UploadFileField']['size'];

    // Removes Unwanted Spaces and characters from the files names of the files being uploaded
    $UploadName = preg_replace("#[^a-z0-9.]#i", "", $UploadName);
    // Upload File Size Limit
    if(($FileSize > 125000)){

        die("Error - File too Big");

    }
    // Checks a File has been Selected and Uploads them into a Directory on your Server
    if(!$UploadTmp){
        die("No File Selected, Please Upload Again");
    }else{
        move_uploaded_file($UploadTmp, "C:/xampp/htdocs/meg/$UploadName");
    }

}

?>
```

It works great and as seen in the 'move_upload_file command it puts them directly into that directory.

However what I am trying to achieve is to upload these files with this form and then to add it to **another** form that is on the same page.

Here is an example of my other form:

```
 <form action="networkCompiler.php" method="POST">
            <h3>Choose Network/Function:</h3>
            <select id ="network" name="network" />
             <option value="networkA">A</option>
             <option value="networkB">B</option>
            </select>
```

So ideally if I upload networkC on the first form, I want it to then display on the second form. I am using PHP primarily on this project and was attempting to find a solution in that language. So far I have tried saving the file upload as a variable and then adding that to the bottom of the form.

```
    <?php 
       if (isset($_POST['UploadButton'])) {
          if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['UploadFileField']['tmp_name'])) {
             $trying = $_POST['FileUploadForm'];
          }
       } 
     ?>
```

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, and what is the question? Is it works or not?

Comment: No, my question was how do I display on the network function form a text file that I uploaded through the file uploader.@Peter

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents()`:

```
<?php
    if(your_condition)
        echo '<option value="the_value_you_want">' . file_get_contents('path_of_uploaded_file') . '</option>';
?>
```

Comment: What would I put where your_condition is? @Cerike

Comment: The condition on which you decide if the `option` should be added or not. For example, you don't want the `option` to be added if there isn't a file uploaded yet. @JasonBruno

Comment: Its not working, still is giving me a blank screen @Cerike.

Comment: How can it give you a blank screen? What happened to the rest of your page? Oh, and I misunderstood your question, let me update the code accordingly.@JasonBruno

Comment: Blank as in yes the rest of the page shows up but it doesnt read the text file at all or run the function on it. It is supposed to take the text file and run it through some java functions to output a result, but its returning nothing. 
Also, the value i want to be stored as a variable as if you or I were to submit a text file it would be named different things and i need the value to reflect that on every single submit. @Cerike.

Comment: Okey, Now I completely don't understand what you want. For one, php is on the server side while java is on the front-end. Other than that, you are talking in riddles! For example: "supposed to take the text file and run it through some java functions to output a result" what? You said, you wanted the content of the file added to the `select` as an option. Please, reword your question to reflect what you need; your sentences are just incoherent and are not making a lot of sense.Till that, I can tell you one thing: file_get_contents(file_location) returns the content of the file as a string.